# Give border title in div

Tags: html, css, forms

Can I do like this in HTML:

[image]

I want to add border title ("General Information" in this image) on my `div`.  Is it possible? How to do it?

---

**Note:**
The image is not HTML page's image, its a Java app's image.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
<div id="form" style="width:350px;">
   <fieldset>
      <legend style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;">General Information</legend>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td><span style="text-decoration:underline">C</span>hange Password To:</td>
            <td><input type="text"/></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><span style="text-decoration:underline">C</span>onfirm Password:</td>
            <td><input type="text"/></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it semantically correctly to use fieldset for a border? I wonder.

Answer (score 22):

The image is possibly using a `fieldset` tag instead of a `div`, inside a `fieldset` you can use the tag `legend` and it will automatically position there.

```
<fieldset>
<legend>General Information</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thnx, It not an html page's image. Its an Java app's image.

Comment: I see, maybe you should add that to the question.

Answer (score 5):

```
<fieldset style="width:100px;">

<legend>

Please Enter Your Name</legend>

<br>

<table>

<tr>

<td>First Name:</td>

<td><input type="text" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Last Name:</td>

<td><input type="text" /></td>

</tr>

</table>

</fieldset>
```

This will givu u output like this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Round Border with Background color.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.sample
{
border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
padding:10px 40px; 
background:#dddddd;
width:300px;
border-radius:25px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sample">
The border-radius property allows you to add rounded corners to elements.

<fieldset style="width:100px;">

<legend>

Please Enter Your Name</legend>

<br>

<table>

<tr>

<td>First Name:</td>

<td><input type="text" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Last Name:</td>

<td><input type="text" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>First Name:</td>

<td><input type="text" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Last Name:</td>

<td><input type="text" /></td>

</tr>

</table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">


</fieldset>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will give output like this,

[image]