# How to give border a title?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I guess its really simple, but I cant find it as I'm don't know how it is called. 
I want to make a border with a title, something like this:

----TITLE_HERE----------------------------------

Comment: You’re probably looking for the [`<fieldset>` and `<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) elements.

Comment: Yes! I forgot their names. Thank you! And I'm sorry for the stupid question... @Xufox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` tags to achieve this, as demonstrated in the code below pulled from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5216144/5812435):

```html
<div id="form" style="width:350px;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;">General Information</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><span style="text-decoration:underline">C</span>hange Password To:</td>
                <td><input type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span style="text-decoration:underline">C</span>onfirm Password:</td>
                <td><input type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, @Xufox wrote it on the comments. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. Hopefully the code example will provide additional help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going for something like this :

```css
fieldset {
    border : none;
    border-top : 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Title</legend>
    Here is some demo content
</fieldset>
```

---

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/po6251dL/).